# How do you get a streamed file uploaded to AWS Lambda in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, stream

I am porting an [express file uploader](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/b782cfa4005930de0b1818c229d192f1) function based on [multer](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html), to AWS Lambda using the new `awslambda.streamifyResponse` global handler wrapper.

```
export const handler = awslambda.streamifyResponse(
  async (
    event: APIGatewayProxyEvent,
    stream: ResponseStream,
    context: Context,
  ): Promise<void> => {
    await dispatch(event.httpMethod, event.path, event, stream, context)
  },
)
```

The `dispatch` function just implements basic routing based on method/path. Inside one of the methods I am doing this:

```
await loadFiles(event, {
  link: [{ path: 'input[file]', max: 1, min: 1 }],
  hook: buildFileHandle(a),
})
```

That `loadFiles` comes from this file (based on the first link above):

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express'
import _ from 'lodash'
import { ReadStream } from 'fs'
import onFinished from 'on-finished'
import busboy, { FileInfo } from 'busboy'
import DEBUG from 'debug'
import kink from './kink.js'
import { Event } from './router.js'

const debug = DEBUG('load-file')

export type HandleFileInput = {
  event: Event
  stream: ReadStream
  file: LoadFile
}

export type LoadFile = {
  name: string
  encoding: string
  mimeType: string
  buffer?: Buffer
  path?: string
}

export type LoadFileLink = {
  path: string
  min?: number
  max?: number
}

export type HandleFile = (
  props: HandleFileInput,
) => Promise<string | Buffer>

export default function loadFiles(
  event: Event,
  {
    link,
    hook,
    halt,
  }: {
    hook: HandleFile
    link: Array<LoadFileLink>
    halt?: {}
  },
) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    let bb: busboy.Busboy

    const fieldMap = link.reduce<Record<string, LoadFileLink>>(
      (m, x) => {
        m[x.path] = x
        return m
      },
      {},
    )

    event.json ??= {}

    bb = busboy({
      headers: event.headers,
      limits: halt,
    })

    let uploadError
    let processing = 0

    // handle text field data
    bb.on(
      'field',
      (
        fieldName: string,
        value: string,
        fieldNameTruncated: boolean,
        valueTruncated: boolean,
      ) => {
        if (fieldName == null) {
          return abort(kink('missing_field_name'))
        }
        if (fieldNameTruncated) {
          return abort(kink('field_name_truncated'))
        }
        if (valueTruncated) {
          return abort(
            kink('field_value_truncated', { name: fieldName }),
          )
        }

        _.set(event.json, fieldName, value)
      },
    )

    let isDone = false
    let readFinished = false

    // handle files
    const files: Record<string, LoadFile> = {}
    const sizes: Record<string, number> = link.reduce<
      Record<string, number>
    >((m, x) => {
      m[x.path] = 0
      return m
    }, {})
    const streams: Record<string, ReadStream> = {}
    const aborted: Record<string, boolean> = {}

    bb.on(
      'file',
      async (fieldName: string, stream: ReadStream, info: FileInfo) => {
        if (!fieldMap[fieldName]) {
          return abort(
            kink('invalid_file_field_name', {
              name: fieldName,
            }),
          )
        }

        sizes[fieldName]++

        const field = fieldMap[fieldName]
        const size = sizes[fieldName]

        if (field?.max && size && size > field.max) {
          return abort(kink('too_many_files'))
        }

        processing++

        const file: LoadFile = (files[fieldName] = {
          name: info.filename,
          encoding: info.encoding,
          mimeType: info.mimeType,
        })

        streams[fieldName] = stream

        const handleClear = () => {
          debug('handle upload stream clear')
          stream.off('clear', handleClear)
          processing--
          process.nextTick(finish)
        }

        const handleError = err => {
          debug('handle upload stream error')
          // stream.off('error', handleError)
          // handled in custom handler
          aborted[fieldName] = true
          stream.emit('abort', err)
          abort(err)
        }

        const handleLimit = () => {
          debug('handle upload stream limit')
          stream.off('limit', handleLimit)
          const err = kink('file_size_limit_reached')
          aborted[fieldName] = true
          stream.emit('abort', err)
          abort(err)
        }

        // emit in custom handler.
        stream.on('clear', handleClear)
        stream.on('error', handleError)
        stream.on('limit', handleLimit)

        try {
          debug('before upload handling')
          const data = await hook({ event, file, stream })
          debug('after upload handling')

          if (data instanceof Buffer) {
            file.buffer = data
          } else if (typeof data === 'string') {
            file.path = data
          }

          _.set(event.json, fieldName, file)

          stream.emit('clear')
        } catch (e) {
          debug('error uploading')
          return abort(e)
        }
      },
    )

    bb.on('error', err => {
      abort(err)
    })
    bb.on('partsLimit', () => {
      // abort(kink('LIMIT_PART_COUNT'))
    })
    bb.on('filesLimit', () => {
      // abort(kink('LIMIT_FILE_COUNT'))
    })
    bb.on('fieldsLimit', () => {
      // abort(kink('LIMIT_FIELD_COUNT'))
    })
    bb.on('finish', () => {
      readFinished = true
      finish()
    })

    req.pipe(bb)

    function abort(err) {
      if (uploadError) {
        return
      }

      debug('stream abort')

      uploadError = err

      for (const fieldName in streams) {
        const stream = streams[fieldName]
        if (stream && !aborted[fieldName]) {
          aborted[fieldName] = true
          stream.emit('abort', err)
        }
      }
    }

    function finalize(err: Error | null) {
      if (isDone) {
        return
      }

      isDone = true

      debug('upload finalize')

      req.unpipe(bb)
      req.on('readable', req.read.bind(req))
      bb.removeAllListeners()

      onFinished(req, () => {
        if (err) {
          return rej(err)
        }
        res(undefined)
      })
    }

    function finish() {
      debug('upload finish')
      if ((uploadError || readFinished) && !processing) {
        finalize(uploadError)
      }
    }
  })
}
```

I'm halfway through porting (it's just simple find-replace of `req.body` with my `event.json` pretty much this far), but getting stuck at the piping parts about halfway down:

```
req.pipe(bb)
req.unpipe(bb)
req.on('readable', req.read.bind(req))
```

This leads me to my main question, **how do you stream the request in AWS lambda?** That is, in my case I will be doing multipart data containing one or more large files (10mb-1gb). I would like to *not* do like the example [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-response-streaming/) and "pretend" the `event` is a stream:

```
exports.gzip = awslambda.streamifyResponse(async (event, responseStream, _context) => {
    // As an example, convert event to a readable stream.
    const requestStream = Readable.from(Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(event)));
    
    await pipeline(requestStream, zlib.createGzip(), responseStream);
});
```

How can you get the streamed multipart form data request, and pipe it into something else (like busboy, in this case, or anything really)?

Comment: Response streaming in lambda changes how the response is handled.  The event object, containing the request data among other values is still parsed from the underlying API by the execution environment as a single element, meaning you can't stream it from the network request.

Comment: Arg, at first I think "wow X technology will be the answer", then I dig in for days on end, only to run into a problem like this, where there's a huge roadblock to the plan. Back to the drawing board I guess! No streaming request! 

Comment: Is it even possible to get a file as a blob/array buffer in the request somehow? Not even streaming, but as a whole downloaded thing?

Comment: The data is stored in the event object.  You can either parse it yourself, or use an existing library like [lambda-multipart-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambda-multipart-parser) to handle the work for you.

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're doing here but be aware that both API Gateway (if you're using it) and Lambda have max synchronous payload limits of 10MB and 6MB respectively.